# Error code 500 while uploading the file on Box Drive

Tags: postman, box

I'm trying to upload file on Box using rest API and getting 500 Internal Server Error.

```
URL: https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content
Header :- "Authorization: Bearer XYZ"
Body(form-data) : attributes='{"name":"test.png", "parent":{"id":""498765432099}}'
file=file will be here
```

Postman screenshot are following:-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys problem is resolved,

I was using the postman from google chrome extension to check the API
and getting 500 in response.

But now I had tested it on postman official application (https://www.getpostman.com/apps) Now it's working fine.

As postman extension is deprecated it still gives me error but on official application its working fine.